# parsing JSON inside of ajax sucess function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I am trying to parse and display this JSON data that gets returned. Basically I have an ajax call which reads an input, sends it via POST to a PHP page and the php page var_dump's the array which contains the data.

```
      array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(21) "jsmith@yahoo.com"
    }
```

My AJAX Call looks like..

```
            <script>
                        function searchDB()
                        {
                              var lookupemail = $('#lookupemail').val();
                              $.ajax({
                              type: "POST",
                              url: "includes/dbsearch.php",
                              data: {wordpress: lookupemail},
                              success: function(server_response)
                              {
                                var response = server.response.1;
                                alert(response);
                              }
                              });
                        }
            </script>
```

How do I retrieve the string that is returned and assign it to a javascript variable?

Comment: Are you actually calling `json_encode()` in your PHP page?  That `print_r()` output is *only* for debugging.

Comment: P.S. If you add `dataType: 'json'` to your `$.ajax` options, then jQuery will run `JSON.parse` for you.

Comment: @RocketHazmat and if it actually is json, the intellegent default probably should have decided it was json already and parsed it for you.

Comment: @TimSeguine: That only works if you have a `Content-type: application/json` header in the response.

Comment: @RocketHazmat doesn't everyone serve requests with proper mime types? ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your PHP code would have to output JSON in the first place:

```
$array = array('jsmith@yahoo.com');
echo json_encode($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it into an array in JavaScript you can use

```
var newArray = $.map(server_response, function(el) { return el; });
```

However, you can access the JSON directly using the json_encode in PHP.

```
json_encode($phparray);
```

and then...

```
server_response.arraykey
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here?